# How to start WFS with layers that are stored in a particular workspace?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I would like to start WFS with layers that are stored in particular workspace. Now my WFS address (ex. domain.com/geoserver/wfs) gives access to layers saveed in all workspaces. Wher to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add your workspace name to the URL - as here:

> 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/*workspace*/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=*workspace*:*featurename*&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json

You can read all about the features provided by virtual services [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/virtual-services.html)

Comment: ignore the quote (') at the start of the url - it's just there to fool the editor in to not recognizing the url.

Comment: It is possible to disable WFS for particular workspaces and eneable it just for one? I would like to serve rest as WMS.

Comment: You'll want the security system in that case http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html#security